# What are dressing transformations, in the context of Poisson-Lie groups?

Tags: poisson-geometry

Hello!

I have some background in Poisson geometry, in particular Poisson-Lie groups and I would like to initiate myself to dressing transformations.

If $(G,\pi)$ is a Poisson-Lie group, then its Lie algebra $\mathcal{G}$ carries a bialgebra structure. Its dual $\mathcal{G}^\star$ is also a Lie bialgebra which can be integrated to a 'dual' Poisson-Lie group $G^*$.

1) How to define the action of $G^*$ on $G$, to identify the orbits of the action, with symplectic leafs of $(G,\pi)$?

2) Are left dressing vector fields hamiltonians?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me, I think that your questions are answered in the paper [Dressing symmetries](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02097626) by Babelon and Bernard.

Comment: Thanks José, for the reference.
The paper by Lu and Weinstein is also a good reference

http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214444324
